# Loading icons for web application dynamically

Tags: extjs, icons, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have ExtJS application and and I develop it sometimes. I don't want to specify each icon explicitly with CSS because there are too much icons ( http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/ ), I just want to write the icon's name and go with it. What kind of solution can help me?

Comment: just generate a CSS file for your icon library, actually, generate it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to do here, but attaining what you want is feasibly impossible.  The way the Extjs library works internally generally uses CSS to define the icons for everything, and CSS is not in itself very easy to create dynamic classes for the icons.

On a lot of components you can just specify the icon image directly though, and in those cases you could do this:
Create a function that only needs the name of the icon as an input and returns the path to the icon with the icon's name:

```
function getIcon(iconName){
    return "\somedirectory\somesubdirectory\" + iconName;
}
```

and everywhere you can, use the 'icon' attribute on components instead of the iconCls attribute.  When you set the icon attribute, you can do this:

```
Ext.create("Ext.button.Button", {
   icon: getIcon("cheese.gif")
});
```